# "Not much of skyscraper by today’s standards, is it really?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

Please help me know, what is the exact meaning of the following sentence and what could be the context where I would use it?

**Not much of skyscraper by today’s standards, is it really?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to add "a" to it
"Not much of a skyscraper by today’s standards, is it really?" then it would be a comparison between a tall building but not massively so. 
It would be a skyscraper (tall building) but not Burj Khalifa tall. 
You could use it by saying "Canary Wharf is a tall building but not much of a skyscraper by today’s standards, is it really?"

Comment: I was a few seconds late. I'll vote up your post -- you were first.

Comment: thanks, doesn't bother me really once the person asking the question understands what we both wrote, essentially the same answer

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

Not much of `a` skyscraper by today’s standards, is it really?

And this sounds even better:

Not much of `a` skyscraper by today’s standards, is it?

The word "really" at the end sounds sort of awkward.

It means `Compared to most skyscrapers today it's not very tall is it?`